# Improving accuracy of classification by inverting predicted labels

Tags: prediction, validation, accuracy

I'm new to machine learning and classifiers output analysis.

Let's say that I have a classifier that correctly classifies my data with an accuracy of **30%** (which is worse than a random one), in a binary classification context.

I can compute that percentage (accuracy) thanks to the *confusion matrix*.

Why can't I say that my classifier is correct at **70%** if I "invert" my *confusion matrix* and say that every instance classified is from the other class?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "inverting" your confusion matrix. A [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) typically matches your classifier's prediction to gold labels that have been established beforehand. So I don't see how you can just turn those labels on their head.

Comment: Imagine that my classifier has to chose between "Black" and "White" as class (binary context). If it is correct at 20%, it has classified 80% wrong. If I take the complementary label for every instance after the computing, I could say that I have a 80% correct classifier ? Perhaps I'm not clear enough.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. But see answer below; also, you are training your classifier on some "black" and "white" data, so if you have to switch things around after prediction it kind of defeats the purpose. Also note that these kind of results can be caused by non-balanced datasets (i.e. if 90 % of the data is "white", an algorithm labeling everything "white" will be do very well in this metric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch the predicted classes that would be considered leakage: you already know such transformation increases accuracy.

Now, if your algorithm learned when to do that transformation, then that would be okay. You can't change parameters knowing the results basically, you need to make your algorithm learn it.

Also, you might consider reporting other, widely accepted, performance measures, such as the class discrimination evaluated by the [AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve).

Comment: If my classifier trains on a given training dataset, and is accurate at 30%, why can't I just, on a test dataset, switch those labels for better accuracy?
What leakage does that imply ?

Comment: If you're tuning the classifier in a training set and changing the classification rule in this way before applying it to "new" data, I don't see a problem with this. That's what the training set is for.

Comment: @not_least_squares what would be the 'accuracy' then ? still the same ?

Comment: The accuracy in the training set is really not important, but it would be the 70%, not the 30%. Because you can make changes like this to perfect training sample accuracy, you can "game" it (e.g. predicting a binary outcome with a very high order polynomial in a quantitative predictor will produce outstanding training sample "accuracy", but probably not in the test data). What's more important is how well the final, fixed, classification rule works in the withheld data.

Comment: @minitapir see I'm talking about the test and validation sets. You can switch the predictions in the training set, that's why I said you should make your algorithm learn it, and then pass this to the test test, without changing it there, as that would be leakage.